# Remove first and second output

Tags: python, for-loop

How can I show output after second one?

Codes:

```
import numpy as np
import pyma


SimpleMA1 = pyma.SimpleMA(3, "0") 
SimpleMA2 = pyma.SimpleMA(3, "0") 

for i in range (6):
    d = SimpleMA2.compute(SimpleMA1.compute((i)))
    print d
```

output is

> 0 
>    0
>    0.33333
>    1
>    2
>    3

I want to remove first and second zero.

Comment: What do you mean - *show output after second one* ? Can you explain with an example, also give what you are getting right now.

Comment: Please update in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always want to remove the first two why not do something like

```
for i in range(6):
  d = SimpleMA2.compute(SimpleMA1.compute((i)))
  if i < 2:
    continue
  print d
```

You could also omit the placeholder ("0" in your case) to output the moving average for all the data provided so far. Or you could filter for the placeholder:

```
for i in range(6):
  d = SimpleMA2.compute(SimpleMA1.compute((i)))
  if d == "0":
    continue
  print d
```

Comment: it is not right. I have again that 2 zero and numbers are completely different

Comment: Oh sorry, I changed the answer

Comment: very nice. is it possible to remove first 4 numbers too?

Comment: Well if you filter for the placeholder, the number of entries does not matter. If you just want to exclude a range replace 2 by 4 or what ever value you need to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the first two outputs, you can let your range start at 2 instead:

```
for i in range(2, 6):
    ...
```

**Edit** or if you don't want to output (print) them, you can replace your print statement with:

```
if i not in range(2):
    print d
```

Or even better (unless you want continuous output while your computation is running)

```
data = [SimpleMA2.compute(SimpleMA1.compute((i))) for i in range(6)]
for d in data[2:]:
    print d
```

Comment: I am using them because `Simple.compute` calculates moving average. it means i need all numbers for calculation but for showing the result ,I dont need to have first two numbers.